# CMS in PHP - Database design

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, content-management-system

I'm beginning web development and started using PHP and MySQL. I'm trying to make a CMS similar to a technical blog and stuck at database design. Each post can be of any one of the following type.

1. Rich text - Single part
2. Rich text - Multiple parts
3. Video link - Single part
4. Video links - Multiple parts
5. Attachment - Single part
6. Attachments - Multiple parts

---

(The attachments can be pdf, doc, ppt)

Each post is under section. The sections are stored in a table. Examples for sections are

Tutorial - all types are allowed
Code snippet - only 1 is allowed
Tips or hacks - only 1,2,3,4 are allowed
News update - only 1 and 3 are allowed
Review - only 1 and 3 are allowed

---

So my question are

1. How do I store and distinguish single and multipart posts?
2. What is the feasible/best way to store attachments?
3. How do I relate sections and posts? ie., How to know/store that a particular section can support post types(all, only 1, only 1 and 2, etc).

Edit:
By single means, I mean 1 post has only 1 part and by multipart I mean 1 post can have several parts

Comment: What do you mean by multipart? Are you talking about merging several posts into one or is this just a fancy word for paragraph?

Comment: Your question(s) is far too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess with "single" you mean that one post is related to one section, multipart means several posts relate to one section?

   db-design could be...

   ```
   table section
   ---------------
   id (int, a-i)
   type (int) 1=tutorial, 2=code-snippet etc.
   name (varchar)
   ...

   table post
   ---------------
   id (int, a-i)
   section_id (int) key to section.id
   ordering (int) if multi for controlling which part is first, second etc. 
   type (int) 1=rich-text, 2=video, 3=attachment  <---- drop single/multi discrimination here
   single (int) 1=yes, 2=no <---- and put it here instead
   content (varchar) --> see below
   description (varchar) of this post
   ```

   note: a single is one post, a multi several post linked to the same section.
2. **where to store attachments:**
   in the file-system of your web server, the db holding the file-name in `table.content`.
   small post-types (e.g. a link) can be stored directly in `table.content`
   --> keeping your db lean and performing
3. **relating sections and posts:**
   by `post.section_id`. Like this, you can link 1 or more posts to a section. use `post.ordering` to put them in the right order.

   ```
   section
   -------------------------- 
   id     | 1
   name   | "How to build a CMS"
   type   | 1 (tutorial) 

   post
   --------------------------
   id         | 1 
   section_id | 1
   ordering   | 0
   type       | 1 (rich-text)
   content    | "/files/130224_1_1_cms.rtf"
   ... 

   id         | 2
   section_id | 1
   ordering   | 1
   type       | 3 (video link)
   content    | "http://www.youtube.com/hgstersh/showid=23jfjr&blabla"
   ...
   ```

   **which `section.type` can have which `post.type`s?**

   - on creating a new section, the `section.type` is set (e.g. drop-down-list in a form)
   - on creating a new post for this section, the drop-down-list for `post-type` offers only permitted types based on `section.type`, this is done in the php-script with `if...` or `switch...case`.

Answer (score 0):

If a post can have multiple images, posts, links that's a one-to-many relationship and the typical schema is:

```
POST: id, title, ...
RICHTEXT: id, post_id, content
LINK: id, post_id, url
```

If you need a many-to-many relationship, for example a story can have many links but the same link can be on multiple stories you would have:

```
POST: id, title, ...
LINK: id, url
POSTS_LINKS: id, post_id, link_id
```

Also take a quick look at schemas for other [popular platforms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)